# Invariance of line integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I need to determine functions $P,Q\in C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ provided that the line integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int_LP(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dx+Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dy
\end{equation}
over closed curve $L$ doesn't depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I am confused because it seems to me that for any two functions $P,Q\in C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ such that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ integral $I$ doesn't depend on $\alpha,\beta$ because of Green theorem.

What am I missing?

Comment: That's correct. But is that the only situation in which it will be true? (In other words, must the integral around every closed curve $L$ be $0$ in order for the integral not to change when you translate the curve arbitrarily?)

Comment: No. But that makes things worse. It adds more possibilities for $P,Q$. How can i find them?

Comment: You obviously need to come up with a way to see what that fact that varying $\alpha$ and $\beta$ doesn't change the integral tells you. Also, note that the problem told you the functions are $C^2$, so you should *expect* to use that.

Comment: Since translating the closed curve $L$ doesn't change integral, then by Green theorem integral remains the same on every closed curve. Then, again by Green theorem, we have that $\int _{[a,b]\times[c,d]} (Q'_x-P'_y)dxdy=constant$ for every rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]\subseteq\mathbb R^2$. From here i think that we can get that $Q'_x-P'_y=0$, but i don't know how. Maybe i can look at the function $F(x,y)=\int_0^x\int_0^y(Q'_x-P'_y)dxdy$. Am i on the right track?

Comment: No one says that $L$ is a rectangle. And the problem refers to one particular $L$, does it not? How do you mathematically study how this quantity changes when you change $\alpha$?

Comment: Well, if i put $\beta=0$ then i have $0=\int_L\frac{P(x+\alpha,y)-P(x,y)}{\alpha}dx+\frac{Q(x+\alpha,y)-Q(x,y)}{\alpha}dy$ and if i let $\alpha\to 0$ then i get $\int_LP'_xdx+Q'_xdy=0$. Thank you very much for your patience btw.

Comment: Interchanging the integral and the limit requires a little proof, but now you're on the right track! Similar result for $\beta$, of course. Note that this limit holds not just at $\alpha=0$ but at any $\alpha_0$.

Comment: Yes, i have that $\int_L\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x,y+\beta)dx+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,y+\beta)dy=0$, for every $\beta\in\mathbb R$. From this i can get $\int_L\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)dx+\frac{\partial ^2 Q}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)dy=0$.

Comment: I am still really lost. Can you help me to proceed?

Comment: I think you get the most basic results by doing the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ derivatives independently. Then use Green's Theorem.

Comment: I've posted an answer, i hope it is correct.

Comment: I disagree with this. There's nothing that says the integral must be $0$ in the first place. I believe that $P=2xy+y^2$, $Q=2xy+x^2$ gives a solution that is not covered by yours.

Comment: I made a mistake in the line before the last one...

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that $\int_LP(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dx+Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dy$ doesn't depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if and only if $\iint_D\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dxdy=0$, where $D$ is a region enclosed by $L$.

If $\iint_D\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dxdy=0$, then $\int_LP(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dx+Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dy$ for every $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by Green theorem.

Lets prove the converse. We have

\begin{equation}
0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}\left(\int_LP(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dx+Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)dy-\int_LP(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy\right)\\
=\int_L\frac{P(x+\alpha,y+\beta)-P(x,y)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}dx+\frac{Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)-Q(x,y)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}dy.
\end{equation}
Thus\begin{equation}
0=\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to (0,0)}\int_L\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\alpha+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}dx+\frac{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\alpha+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}dy
=\iint_D\left(\frac{\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2}\alpha+\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y\partial x}\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}-\frac{\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x\partial y}\alpha-\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}\right)dxdy=\\
\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to (0,0)}\iint_D\frac{            \frac{\partial{\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)}      }     {\partial x}  \alpha               +            \frac{\partial{\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)}      }     {\partial y}  \beta              }{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}dxdy=\\
\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to (0,0)}\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x+\alpha,y+\beta)-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x+\alpha,y+\beta)+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,y)-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)dxdy=\\
2\iint_D\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,y)-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x,y)dxdy
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating under the integral sign tells us that (omitting the arguments $(x+alpha,y+\beta)$ for convenience)
\begin{align*}
0 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\int_L P(x+\alpha,y+\beta)\,dx + Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)\,dy =\int_L \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}dy \quad\text{and} \\
0 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\int_L P(x+\alpha,y+\beta)\,dx + Q(x+\alpha,y+\beta)\,dy =\int_L \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}dy
\end{align*}
Now, letting $\Omega$ be the plane region bounded by $L$, we deduce from Green's Theorem that
$$\int_\Omega \Big(\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y\partial x}\Big)\,dx\,dy = 0 = \int_\Omega \Big(\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x\partial y} - \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}\Big)\,dx\,dy = 0.$$
Certainly any functions $P$ and $Q$ making both these integrands identically $0$ will satisfy the given hypotheses. Without knowing $L$ specifically, that's all I can say.